# i am learning spring boot in intellij ide and making an employee management system with mysql server ,crud rest api and i have encountered a problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot

as in the project i have created many packages and one of the package called mapper having mapping code for employee and employeeDto but i have encountered a problem because i cannot access function called getId() or getfirstName() as i have import employee in the mapper code and in the employee code which was in my entity package i had used @Getter which itself make such functions getId() and getfirstName().Can anyone please tell why its happening.[enter image description here]([enter image description here]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ7iU.png[functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ7iU.png%5Bfunctions) are not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoFjz.png)))
here is the github link for the folder
[github link of project](https://github.com/premmaity/problem)

i have been learning from the udemy course of spring boot [link of course](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-boot-restful-web-services-tutorial-free-course/)

as i am seeing this thing for the first time so i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it seems that you typed manually getter in your class and made a typo.
It should be

```
employee.getId(),
employee.getFirstName(), <- Capital F
employee.getLastName(), <- Capital L
employee.getEmail()
```

not

```
employee.gefirstName(),
employee.getlastName(),
```

Also, make sure that you enable annotation processing.
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > On top check "Enable Annotation Processing"

If that is still causing trouble you can simply drop Lombok and generate getter, setters, and no-arg/arg constructors using IntelliJ, that will work 100%. You can simply right click in your Employee class > Generate > Getters and Setters and remove annotations `@Getter @Setter`, that should be a workaround if your IntelliJ is not recognizing your Lombok annotations

Without Lombok annotations your Employee class should look like this

```
package net.javaguides.ems.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")

public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email_id",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String email;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the video from which i was learning, the man got options like getId() etc after writing employee. But i didnt get such options though i was doing exactly as in the video

Comment: When you write employee and add a dot after it, it does not offer you getFirstName? Did you enable annotation processing as I mentioned in my asnwer ? You can simply let intelliJ generate everything for you instead of using lombok and you will have access to getters in your Mapper class.